# How to simulate the very first start of an app in Xcode 6

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I need to test some behaviors of the iOS 8 at the very first start of my app. Is it possible to simulate this in Xcode 6? If yes, then how?

Comment: Delete app from simulator / Device and run the app afresh.

Comment: I should closer specify what exactly I want to test. I was interested in the very first start of the app before some permissions were determined by the user like access to reminders, calendar events etc. This kind of check is provided on the first start of the app after installation. As @plluke has mentioned, some settings stay cached even after deleting the app. So his solution - reseting settings (if done in the simulator) - is the best for me. Nevertheless thanks to all who tried to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the app will do it but note that certain pieces of information will be cached for a while like your permissions settings (notification, calendar, etc.). You can go to settings.app and reset settings to clear those out if that matters in your use case.

Comment: Much thx. It seems to be the easiest and if done in the simulator the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the FIRST start of the app, then what I did to achive this is, on start (`viewDidLoad`) check in the `NSUserDefaults` for example ,if  the value "hasAlreadyStarted" exists (`NSUserDefaults.objectForKey(..)` ), if not, then its the first start of the app, and then i would set the value to true, so when you close the app, and open again, the value will exist.

Answer (score 0):

Dareon I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. In Xcode 6 yes you can simulate your app from start. If you want to test behaviours I think you are looking for instruments. Right Click on the Xcode icon in your dock select option and choose instruments. You can add several instruments your phone or emulator support like connectivity or gps or memory to see exactly the behaviour of your app. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Well if by very start of the app cycle you mean before the app loads, there is a way. 
In your ViewController call the ViewWillLoad function:

```
class ViewController
{
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

This event will be called before the view loads or appears.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As  Shanti K said in the comment, if you delete your application from the simulator and then run it again, you will be simulating the first run.  To delete the application from the simulator, you mimic the same behavior on a device.

Click and hold on the icon, until they start shaking.  Click the close X next to your application, and verify that you want to delete it if it asks.  Then Shift + Command + H to simulate hitting the home button.